# How to prevent code from running without a file present

Tags: php, if-statement, file-upload

Here is my code

```
if ($error > 0)
   {
   die("Error uploading file! Code $error.");
   }
   else
   {
   if ($type === "image/png" || $type==="image/jpeg" && $size < 122200000)
   {
   $am = move_uploaded_file($temp,"$uploaded/$name");
   }
   else
   {
       die("Format not allowed or file size too big!");
   }
   }
```

This code works perfectly fine. However, I give the user an option to upload an image. If they do not want to upload an image, then I do not want this code to run. I then rewrote the code as follow:

```
if(file_exists($_FILES["image"]))
   {
   if ($error > 0)
   {
   die("Error uploading file! Code $error.");
   }
   else
   {
   if ($type === "image/png" || $type==="image/jpeg" && $size < 122200000)
   {
   $am = move_uploaded_file($temp,"$uploaded/$name");
   }
   else
   {
       die("Format not allowed or file size too big!");
   }
}
}
```

After adding this, this code does not run if no file was entered but if a file was entered, it no longer uploads to my directory. Weird. I tried using **isset($_FILES["image])** however that did not work at all. Any thoughts?

Comment: `if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['error'] == 0) {}`

Comment: you do realise `$_FILES['image']` would be an associative array, so you can't check `if(file_exist()) {...`

Comment: @user3814584 That's okay mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ;

```
if (!empty($_FILES['image'])) 
 {
     // your code to handle update.
 }
```

**NOTE:**

Also you can add check in javascript, to not allow SUBMIT button for Empty file(ie. no file selected.)

Also with

> if(file_exists($_FILES["image"]))

You are checking that file Exist on server.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
   echo "File ". $_FILES['userfile']['name'] ." uploaded successfully.\n";
   echo "Displaying contents\n";
   readfile($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
} else {
   echo "File is not uploaded ";
   echo "Or possible file upload attack: ";
   echo "filename '". $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] . "'.";
}
```

[PHP is_uploaded_file()](http://www.php.net/is_uploaded_file)